# Apache mod_proxy write Post to log file

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, apache-config

Is there any way to capture post request and write it to log running apache mod_proxy (or any other mod)?

For example, I have one CMS behind apache mod_proxy and I want to capture Login textbox which uses POST verb in the apache log file, it is possible?

Thanks :).

Comment: This sounds very much like a phishing attempt.... :)

Comment: Yes it sound quite bad , but it isn´t to phising , it to log and trace access to liferay comunity edition , Audit is only allowed in Enterprise edition ;).

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at [mod_dumpio](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dumpio.html). All input and/or all output will be logged into error.log.

[mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org/) can log post data too, but a little complex.

Comment: We were testing with mod_dumpio , but it doesn´t work properly , because we are running apache as proxy server, we are going to start trying with modsec log, thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

This may suit to your needs [mod_log_post](http://freecode.com/projects/mod_log_post) (striped down version of mod_sec), but has less documentation and support. Though it might work within your purpose.